# Updating prop value in child component from parent Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I want to update a prop in my child component when my parent component updates the value. But I'm doing this a little differently due to which I'm having a problem where the child prop is NOT getting updated.

**meet.vue**

```js
<template>
...
<div>{{ meet.name }} </div>
...
</template>
...
props: ["meet"]
```

**time.vue**

```js
<template>
...
<meet :meet="showMeet(e.id)" /> // id is coming because meet is in a v-for
</template>
...
props: ['events'],
...
methods: {
   showMeet(id) {
      this.events.forEach(e => { if(e.id === id) return e})
   }
}
```

**activity.vue**

```js
<template>
...
<time :events='events' ref="time" />
...
</template>
...
methods: {
   sendEvents(event) {
      // some manipulation to event
      this.$refs.time.showMeet(event.id)
   }
}
```

So as you can see form the components above, I'm manipulating some data (event) in **activity.vue** and calling `showMeet()` which is in the child component. I want to *update* the value in **meet.vue** from **activity.vue**.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't. I feel its because the prop "meet" in **time.vue** is getting its value from a function when it calls it. But in other case (where the parent, **activity.vue** calls it), the prop "meet" doesn't get any value returned. Hence the prop in **meet.vue** is not updated.

Any idea how to update the child? I'm not sure this is the right way to do it, but if someone has a better way, please do let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From vue.js docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, **but not the other way around.**

If you want to update prop you should update parents data instead.
For example, you can use `$emit('input', value)` as shown here
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components